# DropDownListFor selecting wrong value when using a lambda with no argument (closure)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, lambda, closures, html-helper

My index page looks like this:

case1:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyStats.Models.Port>

...
<!-- does not work -->
@Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.Active,new List<SelectListItem>(){ new SelectListItem(){ Text = "True", Value=bool.TrueString}, new SelectListItem(){ Text = "False", Value=bool.FalseString}});

<!-- does work -->
@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Active)
```

*item* is a Port-Model from the enumerable modele defined on top of the file.
*item.Active* is a bool value.
Unfortunately, *DropDownListFor* does not work, the bool values are not set correct. 
But *EditorFor* does work.

And in the edit window, *DropdownlistFor* does work:
case2:

```
@model MyStats.Models.Port
...
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Active,new List<SelectListItem>(){ new SelectListItem(){ Text = "True", Value=bool.TrueString}, new SelectListItem(){ Text = "False", Value=bool.FalseString}})
```

As far as I understand, the difference is, that in case1 the lambda expression is a closure, where item.Active is stored inside, and in case2 the model is passed to the lambda expression at runtime (somewhere in the htmlhelper).
But why is there a difference? It should not matter since in case1 the right value should be extracted from the expression closure. 
And since it works with *EditorFor*, why does it not work with *DropDownListFor*?

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue! Here is what I found after some digging in the MVC source code:

- **Short version:**
  If you use `modelItem => item.Active`, it will not be executed it as a standard .NET expression! Instead, the logic will notice `item.Active` as code, which accesses the `Active` property and will attempt to fetch this property from the model of the page and not from the item you are using!!!
- **Longer version:**
  Here is the source code for the DropDownFor method: [Link](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/SelectExtensions.cs) Notice that the method uses an object called `ModelMetadata` and creates it using `ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData)`.
  Now if you look at `ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression` [here](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/ModelMetadata.cs), notice that the method does not evaluate the expression - it tries to figure out its type. In your case it gets in

  ```
  case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:
      // Property/field access is always legal
      MemberExpression memberExpression = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
      propertyName = memberExpression.Member is PropertyInfo ? memberExpression.Member.Name : null;
      containerType = memberExpression.Expression.Type;
      legalExpression = true;
      break;
  ```

  After this the code will try to access the property on the model of the page and not your item from the closure.

  ```
  TParameter container = viewData.Model;
  Func<object> modelAccessor = () =>
  {
      try
      {
          return CachedExpressionCompiler.Process(expression)(container);
      }
      catch (NullReferenceException)
      {
          return null;
      }
  };
  ```

I hope this helps! I am still trying to figure out how to workaround this :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Active",
 new SelectList( new List<string>() { "True", "False" }, Model.Active.ToString()))
```

I think it is shorter, clearer. When you make a SelectList you can specify the default value manually. Try the DropDownListFor too, it might work with a SelectList instead of an IEnumerable

```
@Html.DropDownList(model => model.Active,
 new SelectList( new List<string>() { "True", "False" }))
```

P.S. In the first example you have typed "modelItem => item.Active" instead of "modelItem => modelItem.Active" I guess.

Comment: thanks. 
but modelItem=>item.Active is correct. This is a lambda where the parameter does not matter.
Actually this is code that is created autom. when using asp.net mvc.
You could also write "bla => item.Active" and it would still work.
The bla is ignored. Only the "item.Active" matters. The "item" is an object in scope and it is stored with the lambda expr. somehow. In that case, the lambda expression is called a closure. 
And thats the difference between the cases. 
In case2 it is "model=>model.Active", the html helper will use the original model to get the active-value from it at runtime.